# Download file from S3 with link in Ruby and 403 Forbidden error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm now trying to implement function that reads the uri of S3 file ( mp4 ) and puts to the rails server.

```
def self.download

uri = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tokbox.com.archive2/45550892%2F324cad13-b447-4d3c-9477-c829665c8180%2Farchive.mp4?forprivacytherestofaddressisnotshownhere'
contents = URI.parse(uri)

File.open('testtest.mp3', 'wb') do |f|
  f.write contents.read
end

end
```

But unfortunately, I'm now seeing these following errors.

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 403 Forbidden
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:353:in `open_http'
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:724:in `buffer_open'
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in `open'
    from /Users/sungpah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:712:in `read'
    from (irb):9:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):8:in `open'
    from (irb):8
```

I've tried to parse uri, or make it string, but it hasn't been working with me.
I'd love to hear any good idea or hunch to move forward!!!

Best

Comment: are you actually able to load that url in the browser?

Comment: OMG, it seems that the url was actually causing the issue. It turns out that the url was expired! Thanks for your comment!